# sql query for selecting data from a table with complex structure

Tags: java, sql, db2

I have a table with below structure.

I am not having control over changing the table.

It has three columns: student_name, student_id, name_id

Now student name could be any number of words. Exactly one word will come in one row. Based on the number of words, name_id will be entered and the student_id will be repeated.

The structure would be some thing like:

say name1 is: Ram Laxman Prasad Sharma

and name2 is: Pandit Gangadhar Vidyadhar Mayadhar Omkarnath Shastri

So the table will look like:

```
student_name  |   student_id    |   name_id
-------------------------------------------------
 Ram                 1               1
 Laxman              1               2
 Prasad              1               3
 Sharma              1               4
 Pandit              2               1
 Gangadhar           2               2
 Vidyadhar           2               3
 Mayadhar            2               4
 Omkarnath           2               5
 Shastri             2               6
```

I hope I explained the structure clearly.

Now, I want to write a query to read only first four names per student. However, if the number of names is less then four, empty string should go and if its greater then four, first four should go and rest just ignored.

I need to put it in a single select query only, since this query will be passed in a spring batch program. But I am not getting how to loop through nameid column to take first four name id for every student.

How to design this sql for DB2 database v8??

Thanks for reading.

Comment: oh v8 :(( in newest versions you could use `xmlcast(xmlgroup(...`, but have a look at [xmlagg()](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref/fxmlagg.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

improved version inspired by Amit - if you need all 4 names in 1 column :)

```sql
  select
    t1.student_name || 
    coalesce(' ' || t2.student_name, '') ||
    coalesce(' ' || t3.student_name, '') ||
    coalesce(' ' || t4.student_name, '') as "first 4 names"
  from mytable t1
  left join mytable t2 on t1.student_id = t2.student_id and t2.name_id = 2
  left join mytable t3 on t1.student_id = t3.student_id and t3.name_id = 3
  left join mytable t4 on t1.student_id = t4.student_id and t4.name_id = 4
  where t1.name_id = 1
```

Comment: It works... However, I need to take it in separate fields as mentioned.. As I have to send them to a fixed format file downstream.. trying to do that..

Comment: separate **columns** or separate **rows**??? i didn't find that requirement in your question..

Comment: columns are easy, for rows you have to use `with temp (student_name, name_id) as values('', 1), ('', 2), ... select * from mytable cross join temp` - i hope you figure it out on your own, because i have to catch a train

Answer (score 2):

First off, I don't have DB2, so there may be some syntax changes

Try the following

```
select t1.student_id, ifnull(t2.names, ' ') from
(select distinct(student_id) as student_id 
 from tab ) as t1
left outer join
(
select tab1.student_id, ifnull(concat(tab1.student_name, ' ',
   tab2.student_name, ' ',
   tab3.student_name, ' ',
   tab4.student_name),'') as names
from (select * from tab where name_id = '1') tab1
inner join (select * from tab where name_id = '2') tab2
on tab1.student_id = tab2.student_id
inner join (select * from tab where name_id = '3') tab3
on tab1.student_id = tab3.student_id
inner join (select * from tab where name_id = '4') tab4
on tab1.student_id = tab4.student_id
) as t2
on t1.student_id = t2.student_id
```

I've worked on the assumption that your name_id are chars. Also keep in mind that I had written this query for MySQL and DB2 may have a different syntax

Comment: I think you have assumed here that there will always be four words. What if there are only three words. What will happen to last inner join. Won't it fail ?

Comment: @AmitBhargava now it's not that much fixed as more complicated and still returns ' ' if a student has 2 names :(( but i keep +1 for the inspiration..

Comment: This is not working.. first reason - what will go in tab4.student_name as name4 when only three words are present ?

Comment: @NikunjChauhan If the student has less than four names, this returns ' ' as stated in the question. Did I misinterpret this?

Comment: @AmitBhargava: Thanks! +1 for the effort!